# using dplyr window function lag (SQL database)

Tags: sql, r, sqlite, lag, dplyr

on a SQLite database with weather informations (colums: DATE, DOY, TEMPERATURE) I like to *add* a new column with *temperature sums* (the sum of daily *TEMPERATURE* from January 1 to the current day). (DOY is the *day of the year*.)

The dplyr windows functions should be suitable to solve this *problem*. http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/window-functions.html. Perhaps something like

```
mutate(TEMPERATURESUM = lag(TEMPERATURE, DOY, order_by=DATE))
```

but it gives an `error in statement: no such function: LAG`

Do you know an example from which I see how I'm doing it correct? I do not like to use pure SQL where there are so comfortable ways with dplyr.

thx
Christof

Comment: A simple test with `mtcars %>% mutate(lagged = lag(mpg, 1, order_by=carb))` seems to work. What type of object are you piping to `mutate`? What dplyr version are you using?

Comment: Could you please provide a reproducible example, including the dataset? In any case, from the dataset it sounds like you are misspelling `lag` as `LAG`

Comment: Are you looking for cumsum of temperature from jan 1 to current day perhaps?

Comment: @MrFlick the object is a SQLite Database, @David `lag` is converted to LAG in SQL (SQL is case insensitivity) and LAG does not exist in SQL :( @docendo thx for the tipp, but unfortunately I get the same error with `cumsum`because it seems not to be translated in an SQL equivalent

Comment: Are you opposed to doing this with your own SQL code? There are a few SO answers on cumulative sums with sqlite, seems to be pretty straightforward, e.g. [this recent one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21382766/cumulative-summing-values-in-sqlite).

Comment: SQLite does not support window functions, so you can't use `lag()` etc with it

Answer (score 1):

If you are not opposed to using raw SQL code, you could do this using `library(rsqlite)`:

```
# SQL statements we want to run
sql1 <- "
ALTER TABLE t
ADD COLUMN tempsum real;"

sql2 <- "
UPDATE t
SET tempsum = (SELECT Sum(t2.temperature) 
               FROM t as t2 WHERE t2.doy <= t.doy);" 

dbSendQuery(conn, sql1)
dbSendQuery(conn, sql2)
```

This is adapted from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21382766/cumulative-summing-values-in-sqlite) about cumulative sums in SQLite, and an [example showing it works on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/6d11b/21) (which I learned about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120544/how-to-get-cumulative-sum)).

But then I guess you could also just calculate the cumulative sum in R and write the results back to SQLite, if the table is not too big, so I'm not sure if your question was specifically about how to do this with `dplyr`, or how to do it in general.

Comment: thank you very much for the example. I will probably do it that way. Maybe it is not currently possible with `dplyr`in a simpler way _on the fly_